How many parts will the space be divided into if each face of one regular pyramid is infinitely extended?
Recently, a high school student in domestic community shared one math problem: How many parts will the space be divided into if each face of one Square Pyramid is infinitely extended?
But I couldn't find the correct answer that high school students could still understand.
Futhermoer, for right regular prism and Regular Pyramid
Let $A (n)$ and $B (n)$ represent the number of parts  into which the space is divided after extending infinitely  all faces of  right regular prism and regular Pyramid whose base is a regular polygon with n sides respectively.
Consider regular polygons on a plane，Obviously $A (3)=21=(3*2+1)*3$ ,$A (4)=27=(4*2+1)*3$，$A(5)=48=(5*3+1)*3$, $A (6)=57=(6*3+1)*3$，$A (8)=99=(8*4+1)*3$····
I wonder if $A(n)=3\{n[(n+1)/2]+1\}$ is right?
And I don not know how to calculate $B (n)$

The text of the question should be able to stand alone, so please don't only put the question in the title. The title talks about dividing the space into some parts, the text says that the cylinder and the sphere is divided into some parts? And why is it obvious (it's not to me) that the cylinder (I assume you're talking about cylinders with a circular base?) gives 9?

What does "one geometry" mean? Do you mean a convex polyhedron?

Sorry, I have re-edited again, If only considering orthoprisms and orthopyramid. Let $N$ represent the number of parts that space is divided into, and I wonder if there are some general conclusions ,e.g. $N$ can be represented by $V$, $E$, and $F$.

Personally, I never heard of the "orthopyramid" and "orthoprism" (and I am a professional geometer). And your penultimate sentence makes no sense at all.

Thank you for your reply. I have re-edited the question and hope there are no issues this time.

For prisms they have 2 bases parallel to each other. So the no of parts will be 3 times the number of parts divided by lateral faces. But there is no definite formula as for pentagonal Prism we can have 48 as well as 42 parts. Looking from top we can get 16 well as 14 partition by lateral faces.

Therefore there is no definite formula for prism(irregular).

tks, If only considering orthoprisms and orthopyramid. Is there any definite formula?
